# How can I make the RadioButtons on my DataGrid stay usable after sorting?

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid, radio-button

I have a **DataGrid** that I am creating and populating from code. When the grid first shows up the **RadioButton** column, "Include", seems to work just fine.  The problem is that after I change the sort the RadioButton **no longer works** correctly.  You can spam click on it, click out of the window and then come back in, or maybe event just wait, it will eventually work, but obviously it isn't really usable.  Here is an simple example:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeDataGrid();
        }

        private void InitializeDataGrid()
        {
            var table = GetTestTable();

            var newGrid = new DataGrid
                              {
                                  CanUserAddRows = false,
                                  CanUserSortColumns = true,
                                  AutoGenerateColumns = true,
                                  ItemsSource = table.AsDataView(),
                                  DataContext = table
                              };
            newGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn += dataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn;

            UxRootGrid.Children.Add(newGrid);
        }

        private static DataTable GetTestTable()
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable("name");
            table.Columns.Add("Include", typeof (bool));
            table.Columns.Add("Number", typeof (int));

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                var row = table.NewRow();
                row[0] = false;
                row[1] = i;
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            return table;
        }

        void dataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName != "Include")
            {
                return;
            }

            DataTemplate template = GetDataTemplate();
            DataGridTemplateColumn templateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn
                                                        {
                                                            Header = "Include",
                                                            CellTemplate = template,
                                                            CellEditingTemplate = template,
                                                        };
            e.Column = templateColumn;
        }

        private static DataTemplate GetDataTemplate()
        {
            var elementFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof (RadioButton));

            var binding = new Binding("Include")
                              {
                                  Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
                                  UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
                              };

            elementFactory.SetBinding(ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty, binding);
            elementFactory.SetValue(RadioButton.GroupNameProperty, "BindingGroup");

            return new DataTemplate {VisualTree = elementFactory};
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel Name="UxRootGrid">
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

So, to see the problem:
1. Start the application
2. Click on the RadioButton next to the Number 1.
3. Click on the "Number" header twice (to sort in descending order).
4. Now click on the RadioButton next to the Number 4.
5. Notice that the RadioButton next to the Number 1 is now deselected, but that the RadioButton next to the Number 4 is not selected.
6. Click on the RadioButton next to the Number 4 a few more times.  Eventually it will become selected.

UPDATE: I had another of my coworkers try this on his machine, and it took him a time or 2 more of sorting / selecting radio buttons to see the issue happen, but eventually he ended up in the same position as me.

I'm pretty new to WPF, so I'm hoping this is just a simple mistake on my part.  Any help in getting a workaround or another method of setting this up would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked that the binding to "Include" works?
Seems to me that problem is there...

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors with the binding (at least no errors are showing up in my output).  I assume the binding is working at least partially, because if you change the 
row[0] = false; 
to 
row[0] = true;
then you will notice it is populating the last RadioBox correctly.

Comment: @Bob, I tried doing an update layout as part of the sorting, but that didn't seem to help.  Where would you suggest trying to add that?

Comment: @Dusan, I added a private member to my class to keep track of the DataTable I created.  I then added an event handler to the elementFactory so that I could handle the CheckedEvent.  Inside the event I just verified that the DataTable was being updated correctly.  Further, when you sort the column the value is not lost, indicating that the value was written correctly.  The problem is just that after sorting you quickly lose the ability to select a new  value.

Comment: Where are you updating the layout? You should be doing it on the overall view. So MainWindow.UpdateLayout() or whichever is highest level. Also check the Output tab in Visual Studio to make sure it wasn't a binding or other issue.

Comment: The UpdateLayout is not included in the sample code I posted because it did not appear to have any effect.  I setup a handler for the Sorting event on the DataGrid, and set it in there.  I had been trying to do the UpdateLayout on the DataGrid, but trying MainWindow.UpdateLayout() doesn't seem to do anything either.

Comment: @Bob. I really don't think it is a layout issue.  I added code into the CheckedEvent handler to just dump out the current state of the table when it is clicked.  I can see it appropriately updating the include column.  After I do the sort, when I click the RadioButtons the underlying DataTable just shows False in the Include column for each row.  After spam clicking and getting it to start responding again, the output starts showing up as I would expect again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by using the *RadioButtonExtended* class by Peter Staev, located here: http://pstaev.blogspot.com/2008/10/binding-ischecked-property-of.html

As he suggests in his post, I just replaced the usages of *RadioButton* with *RadioButtonExtended* and then did my binding to *IsCheckedReal* rather than *IsChecked*.